# Using ShapeOrientation plugin QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I'm trying to use shapeorientation in QGIS, but it doesn't create a new attribute table in my shapefile. When I open the csv file it's empty. Does anyone know if i need to an installation on PYTHON in QGIS with this plugin?

Comment: What operative system do you have?

Comment: I have windows 10

Answer (score 2):

I installed and ran this plugin and I didn't have any issue; as it can be observed at following image:

[image]

It was also verified that cvs file was adequately written in specified directory:

**/home/zeito/Desktop/QGIS Projects**

in above image.

I searched in **ShapeOrientation_engine.py** of this plugin and it requires **matplotlib.pyplot** and **pylab** python modules.

Try following commands in your Python QGIS Console:

```
>>>import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>>from pylab import *
```

and post as commentary what was the result.

Comment: I've tried to follow those commands but it doesn't answer anything. It seems that Python QGIS doesn't find matplotlib. Do you know how to install matplotlib on QGIS? I use QGIS 2.18. Thanks for your helpfulness!

Comment: So, probably you have pip installed in your Windows 10. Try in OSGeo system console (as Administrator) this command: `pip install matplotlib`.  If not result try: `easy_install matplotlib`.

Comment: After following this command in OSGeo, pip install matplotlib, the result is: Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using". After trying with easy_install matplotlib, the result is: "easy_install" is not recognised as internal or external program, a feasible program or a batch file.

Comment: I've tried as you suggest but in both case unfortunately I don't have any result. If I send you my linear shapefile could you please calculate orientation with ShapeOrientation plugin? And then you might send it to me by email. I would be really grateful to you